Problem involving multiple inheritance in Java
This question appeared on a test paper in my college.

Q. Assume that you have been given the following diagram:

Here, A, B, D, and H are classes. Class A is inherited by classes C and F, and
so on. Assume that class A has two functions: Addition() and Subtraction(), whereas
class B has two functions: Multiplication() and Subtraction() and class D has one
function: Division(). In the main program, we create the object of class H. We want
to use the Addition(), Subtraction(), Multiplication() and Division() functions. Then
write the pseudocode in Java with the following conditions below.
a. If we don't redefine any functions in class H.
b. If we redefined some functions in class H.

I'm new to the concept of object oriented programming. From what I can tell, the question must be wrong or there is something that I don't understand. Java does not support multiple inheritance, but the diagram clearly shows its use.
If this were C++, we can just inherit the classes as virtual classes and the program should work as intended. As for class H, we will override as needed.
Another interpretation was that we'll only follow a single path along the diagram but that still leads to ambiguity. The concept of interfaces doesn't apply as the question specifically mentions classes.
So for my question- Is this question even correct? If so, how can we do it in java?

Please [edit] your question to include the original assignment given to you. Maybe you are missing some crucial information from the assignment.

The question also says to use "pseudocode" meaning they don't expect a perfect syntax.  Possible the instructor just wanted a general kind of answer.

Hello StrawberryVanilla, You are not interpreting the diagram well, in it, the relationships are indicated, you do not necessarily need to specify each of them in the code, for example, if "F" extends "E", indirectly it is extending "A", since "E" extends "D" and it extends "C" and the latter to "A".

@Progman I have copy and pasted the question as it appeared on the test.

@StrawberryVanilla It still doesn't really make any sense. Please add a link to the original PDF file or the assignment page (whatever you have) as an accessible link to your question. Maybe the question makes more sense in the context of the other questions in the same assignment (if there are any).

Are you sure this question is related to the Java Programming Language as indicated (required) by the [tag:java] tag? Java does not support multiple inheritance regarding classes, that is, a class cannot have more than one parent class; actually every class that is not java.lang.Object has exactly ONE parent class (no more, no less) --- (that is not the case regarding interfaces)

We also have some misleading/incomplete information: 1) "Here, A, B, D, and H are classes." - so the other nodes  are not classes? 2) "is inherited by classes C and F" - now C and F are classes, despite not listed in first part?
